# Entity Framework 4. Join Tables. Entity Framework perfoming an Insert when no action is required

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a database setup with the following: -

```
Person Table  
Hobby Table
Game Table  
GameInfo Table
```

Person [1 - M] Hobby [1 - M] Game [M - 1] GameInfo

`Game` is just a join from `Hobby` to `GameInfo`

I am having an issue whereby I would fetch `Person` which has a `Collection<Game>` and add to this collection (i.e. I am just updating links, not wanting to insert new `GameInfo`).

Upon Calling `SaveChanges()` EntityFramework will insert the links AS WELL AS inserting new `GameInfo`, which is not my desired result.

I have looked at Entry().State etc but the problem is where I am handling the updates of my `Person` is outside of the context.

I am basically fetching a `Person` creating a new `Game` with Ids that I know exist already and then calling the `SaveChanges()` and would expect that it would just insert into the `Game` Table, not the GameInfo table

EDIT 1: Code Sample - sort of

```
public void Save(Profile profile)
{
    using (GDContext context = GetContext())
    {
        DataProfile dataProfile = context.Profiles.Single(u => u.ProfileId == profile.Id);
        ProfileHandler.HandleDataModelChanges(dataProfile, profile);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public override void HandleDataModelChanges(DataProfile dataModel, Profile model)
{
    dataModel.ProfileId = model.Id;
    dataModel.FirstName = model.FirstName;
    dataModel.LastName = model.LastName;
    dataModel.DateOfBirth = model.DateOfBirth;
    dataModel.Email = model.Email;

    foreach(var hobby in model.Hobbies)
    {
        DataHobby dataHobby = dataModel.Hobbies.SingleOrDefault(p => p.HobbyId == hobby.HobbyId);

        if (dataHobby == null)
        {
            dataHobby = new DataHobby();
        }

        HobbyHandler.HandleDataModelChanges(dataHobby, hobby);
    }
}

public override void HandleDataModelChanges(DataHobby dataModel, Hobby model)
{
    dataModel.HobbyId = model.Id;

    HandleGames(dataModel, model);

    HandleCrafts(dataModel, model);

    HandleCollections(dataModel, model);
}

private void HandleGames(DataHobby dataModel, Hobby model)
{
    IEnumerable<DataGame> gamesToRemove = dataModel.Games.Where(g => !model.Games.Any(ds => ds.Id == g.GameId)).ToArray();

    foreach (var game in gamesToRemove)
    {
        dataModel.Games.Remove(game);
    }

    foreach (var game in model.Games)
    {
        if (!dataModel.Games.Any(e => e.GameId == game.Id))
        {
            DataGame dataGame = new DataGame();
            dataGame.GameId = game.Id;
            dataGame.GameName = game.Name;

            dataModel.Games.Add(dataGame);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2 - Context configuration

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;

public GameInfoConfiguration()
{
    HasKey(x => x.GameId);
    ToTable("GameData");
}

public PersonConfiguration()
{
    HasKey(x => x.PersonId);

    ToTable("Person");
}

public HobbyConfiguration()
{
    HasKey(x => x.HobbyId);

    HasRequired(x => x.Person).WithMany(x => x.Hobbies);

    HasMany(x => x.Games).WithMany(g => g.Hobbies).Map(x => x.MapLeftKey("HobbieId").MapRightKey("GameId").ToTable("PersonGame"));

    ToTable("HobbyGame");
}
```

Comment: I think showing some code snippet will make scenario much more clear then trying to explain it. Show small code example where is visible how your entities are created / retrieved and how you handle contexts + inserting entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I still don't see where you work with `GameInfo` - your description absolutely doesn't correspond with your code. By looking at your code I guess the problem will be in the snippet like this:

```
foreach (var game in model.Games)
{
    if (!dataModel.Games.Any(e => e.GameId == game.Id))
    {
        DataGame dataGame = new DataGame();
        dataGame.GameId = game.Id;
        dataGame.GameName = game.Name;

        dataModel.Games.Add(dataGame);
    }
}
```

This will always insert a new `Game` - you told EF to insert a new `Game`. If you want to add existing `Game` you must do:

```
foreach (var game in model.Games)
{
    if (!dataModel.Games.Any(e => e.GameId == game.Id))
    {
        DataGame dataGame = new DataGame();
        dataGame.GameId = game.Id;
        dataGame.GameName = game.Name;

        context.Games.Attach(dataGame); // Now the context knows that it is not a new entity 
        dataModel.Games.Add(dataGame);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks yes I have been reading about this Attach() method, the problem is that I dont have a reference to the context at the point where I am building up my POCO class

I have done similar things to this in previous entityFramework releases don't see why this behaviour has changed.

Comment: just to answer to the query where my explanation didnt match my code.
The problem was I was trying to simplify my problem to begin with.

Comment: I think it was same in previous version. You don't need to use `Attach` only if you load the existing object from database instead of creating new instance in code.

Comment: Well but if you make simplification your code must correspond to the simplification = you must reduce the code to the part which doesn't work.

Comment: just realised where GameInfo went...
would be the var in model.Games :)

GameInfo is my "DomainModel" for "DataGame" as it were...

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake I have made here is that I am dealing with `DataGame` when really what I should be dealing with is a POCO class to represent the "join" between `DataGame` and `Hobby` Like a `HobbyGame` POCO.